# GridDB Error Code (TXN_REPLICATION_LOG_LSN_INVALID) - Replication Failure in Cluster

Tags: java, griddb

I'm facing an issue with GridDB and seeking clarification on how to handle it effectively.

Error Message: TXN_REPLICATION_LOG_LSN_INVALID

Description: Execution of replication failed.

```java
    ReplicationInfo replInfo = new ReplicationInfo();
    replInfo.setMode(ReplicationMode.NORMAL);
    replInfo.setNotificationAddress(notificationAddress);
    replInfo.setNotificationPort(notificationPort);
    gridStore.setReplicationInfo(replInfo);

  // Perform data operations
  // (e.g., put, get, etc.)

    gridStore.disconnect();
```

The error explanation suggests that a failure may have occurred within the cluster, leading to the replication failure.

According to the provided countermeasures, the cluster control section is expected to automatically detect the replication failure and perform recovery processing. Hence, no manual response is required.

Despite understanding the automatic recovery process, I would like clarification on how the cluster control section detects and handles replication failures. Additionally, are there any specific configurations or settings I should check to ensure the smooth operation of replication in my GridDB cluster?

Any insights or guidance on resolving this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!